# How do I take Payload URL from Webhook and make an API Call in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I learned to make API calls and listen to webhooks through Zapier but I would like to know if there is a way to just do it without Zapier because the costs are quite expensive.

In plain JavaScript, is there a way to listen to a webhook, parse the data (this part I know how to do in JS), and then make an API call?

The screenshot is how it's set up in Zapier. I can't find out how to do it in Google and it seems like there would be a way to do it because Zapier didn't always exist. Thank you for your help.

I'm looking for plain JavaScript solutions or links to plain JavaScript solutions (no node or react  because we don't have that). How do are credentials kept safe?

[image: How I set it up in Zapier]

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: What specifically are you looking to do?  It's not entirely clear to me what specifically "listen to a webhook" means in this context.  As for making API calls, there's the `fetch` API as well as 3rd party tools like Axios.  If you're looking to learn JavaScript in general then you'd start with tutorials on JavaScript.  Can you clarify what specifically you're trying to ask?

Comment: We use Discourse forums, and every time a user does something, I get notified by a webhook that has a payload URL. I take that URL and it is my trigger in Zapier. Then when it comes in, I look for the "user created or logged in event" and the email of the person who logged in by parsing the JSON with JavaScript. Once I get the email, I make an API call to Klaviyo and attach the email to a metric in Klaviyo which posts this information to the person's account.

You mentioned Fetch - how do I add the webhook part to that?

Comment: @seon: So by "webhook" in this case you mean that some external system makes an API call to your Zapier system?  If you're looking to replace that then you're looking at hosting a server of some kind.  Doing that with JavaScript means using NodeJS, which you specifically indicated that you don't want to do.  You can host an API endpoint in any server-side technology that you want, but can't host one with only client-side technologies.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck.
So leave a question, show us your code, what did you try and your research:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> In plain JavaScript, is there a way to listen to a webhook

To answer this quickly, no. A webhook is nothing more then the host (Discourse in your case) sending your app some data, now its is explained in a pretty simple manner it can be done more complex but as you've explained it seems to be a more simple webhook. Since you've mentioned you want plain javascript without node its not possible like you are asking.

since you cannot create an endpoint on the client for Discourse to send its information to, there is no way for you to intercept it without a server (Node for example)

I hope this answers your question and that I understood it correctly.

Comment: I see. That's what David said too. I am not familiar with server-side technologies. Is there one that is simple and easy to pick up that works with plain JavaScript? Is that Node?

Comment: Node = Javascript, but on the server.

The simplest you can make is probably using [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/)
To give you a small example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-sha5xb?file=index.js

Is this a very simple barebones example? yes, but you can always read more documentation of express.js yourself, its pretty easy and straightforward.